# IBInspectable does not work for Int or UInt

Tags: ios, xcode, ibinspectable

```
@IBInspectable  var numLines:UInt! = 2
```

The above code shows a message

> Failed to set (numLines) user defined inspected property
>
> UIViewNewClass [setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key numLines.

It does work with another `IBInspectable` property which is `UIColor`.

Does `IBInspectable` work with `Int` or `UInt` or am I doing something wrong here or it works only with `NSNumber`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work with `Int`, `UInt`, or any other numeric type. I've verified this locally with the code below:

```
@IBDesignable
class TestViewController: UIViewController {
    ...

    @IBInspectable var test: UInt = 0

    ...
}
```

This is showing up and working in interface builder as expected. I would make sure you have @IBDesignable on your class definition and also try doing a clean and deleting derived data.

Comment: Yeah, I did Clean and build, but that did not work. So, closed the Xcode , opened it again and then it worked with no errors.